# Adding multiple checkbox prices together in VS

Tags: c#, checkbox

Im trying to make it so a user can select one or multiple extra costs and then it adds into one total. But for some reason when the user selects more than one checkbox it only says the price of one of the selected check boxes.

```
if (CheckBXAccess.Checked)
{
extracost = 1;
extracost += 1;
}
else if (CheckBXTrainer.Checked)
{
extracost = 20;
extracost += 20;
}
else if (CheckBXDiet.Checked)
{
extracost = 20;
extracost += 20;
}
else if (CheckBXVideo.Checked)
{
extracost = 20;
extracost = +20;
}
else return;
Extrachargetxtbx.Text = extracost.ToString();
```

I want the end result to have the extra charge txt bx display the overall cost of whatever chosen text boxes they have selected.

Comment: Do not use "else".  Else is only allowing one checkbox values to be added.

Comment: When I delete "else" nothing comes into the extra charge text box no matter what is clicked.

Comment: You also need to make extracost +=.  Each if is setting value to a fixed number and you want to add to value.

Comment: Do you mean extracost += 20; ? If so I tried that as well.

Comment: Yes.  You need to remove the else and remove the statements with the equals.  Only keep the "+=" lines.

Comment: Brilliant thank you @jdweng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "else" from the statements, remove the initialization of "extracost", and set the text before the return.
your code will be like:

```
if (CheckBXAccess.Checked)
{
    extracost += 1;
}

if (CheckBXTrainer.Checked)
{
    extracost += 20;
}

if (CheckBXDiet.Checked)
{
    extracost += 20;
}

if (CheckBXVideo.Checked)
{
    extracost = +20;
}

Extrachargetxtbx.Text = extracost.ToString();
return;
```